# extensive and strategic game

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

definitions of extensive and strategic (normal) games are very different. 
Here is the question, what would you call a game which is extensive but in each step strategic.

For instance at each step both players choose to play or not simultaneously and each step is also affected by previous steps.

If someone has seen such a thing in any paper or textbook, please refer to it.

Comment: I am not that familiar with the types of games mentioned here, but it seems that the tag combinatorial-game-theory does not apply, as such games are not combinatorial.

Comment: There are no "extensive games" and "normal games". A game in extensive form can also be represented in normal form. That mix-up notwithstanding, you might be looking for "repeated game".

Comment: Your example game is an extensive form game, although some steps are taken simultaneously (which, in the tree, is represented as one information set).

Answer (score 3):

In the book *Game Theory* by Fudenberg and Tirole, they call such games *multi-stage games with observed actions*. These are games where there are rounds (finitely or infinitely many), and in each round player simultaneously choose some action which is observed afterwards. PAyoffs may depend in any way on the whole sequence of action profiles constituting a play.

Special cases of such multi-stage games with observed actions are [repeated games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_game) (there are extensions that do not fit into this framework) and [stochastic games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_game) (at least as far as their game tree is concerned).

Answer (score 0):

Osborne and Rubinstein have an advanced textbook that deals with these issues, such as repeated games and representing simultaneous moves in extensive form.  http://books.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/
I also like Jim Friedman's books, and he was an early master of repeated games. [http://www.amazon.com/Theory-Applications-Economics-James-Friedman/dp/0195036603](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195036603)